# wordpress and permalink not updating

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have to tried to update the permalink in my wordpress site to be post name. I have have .htaccess file uploaded and permission set to 777. However, when I updated the permalink in wordpress it still said :

> If your .htaccess file were writable, we could do this automatically,
>   but it isn’t so these are the mod_rewrite rules you should have in
>   your .htaccess file. Click in the field and press CTRL + a to select
>   all.

If you access to website now (https://www.pata.org/store) and go to any page, it will show up 404 not found page.

One more thing, the website is based on Woocommerce latest version, I am not sure if that is the reason.

Has anybody ever experienced this?

Comment: first, you should never need to use 777. Too open and security risk. Second, for `files` the equivalent should be 666 not 777 as used for directories. 3rd, it's probably an ownership problem. Change the .htaccess perms back to 644 and `chown` it to your webserver user. On ubuntu it's `www-data`  centos user is `apache`

Comment: Hi Panama, Thank you for your answer. I have set the .htaccess back to 644. Now, I have more question about how to chown. The hosting I'm using is Bluehost. Can I chown in cPanel? Thank you

Comment: I do not know sorry. You might want to google that for cpanel. i don't use control panels. Just command line.

Comment: That's good. Thank you :)